# jQuery not working in HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried multiple variations of importing jQuery, but nothing is working. When I run it, everything in the body shows up, but the jQuery function doesn't work.
Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('select').on('change',function(){
            var value=$(this).val();
            var output='';
            for(var i=1;i<=value;i++)
            {
                output+='<div>Your Text</div>';   
            }
            $('#test').empty().append(output);
        });
    }); 

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <span id="test">
    </span>
</body>

</html>
```

What can I do to fix it?

Here are the errors I'm getting in my console:

> The resource from
>   “https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.mi%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%80%B9n.js”
>   was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff).  testy.html
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]
>
> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/e6u5w8ag/. What errors in the console do you get?

Comment: Also use absolute URL, sometime some of the browsers just block the content which is coming from untrusted source, use:
`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: OP is doing a `$(window).load()`, no need to worry about the location of the JS

Comment: It works on jsfiddle for me too, but not when put into a separate file and run in the browser. Not sure why that is, and that's real problem here. Something is missing that jsfiddle has that I don't, and I don't know what that is.

Comment: try `$(document).ready(function(){` instead of `$(window).load(function(){`

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools (F12 in Chrome and FF) and go tot he console tab and reload your page. Then see what errors it shows.

Comment: @Mairaj why would that make a difference?

Comment: @borkborkbork  Are you using any web server to fetch the file? seems jQuery is loading using `file://` protocol

Comment: @borkborkbork, How are you using the file in your application?

Comment: @Mairaj `$(window).load()` actually finishes after `$(document).ready()`. So it shouldn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: press f12 and navigate to console. show us the error

Comment: @borkborkbork  are you getting any error in browser console? are you running this file with `.html` extension?Only this much code you have or some more code is there?

Comment: Try copying that link to your browser and viewing it. Then just copy the entire contents that is being viewed to a `.js` file and refer to that file in your HTML code!

Comment: try to download jquery.js and load it locally, not CDN
then try change `$(window).load(function(){` to `$(window).on('load',function(){` which is more correct

Comment: only adding `https` in the jquery url worked for me. only problem i can see there is if you select `option 1` first it does not work. But if you add any other option first and then add the `option 1`, then it works again. Some sort of logical issue. Recheck your logic.

Comment: Try `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ` instead of direct http or https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Do below steps:-***

Copy the jquery library code (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js) code and save it with the same name in your current working directory (`jquery.min.js`):-

Now use this code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"><!-- this is for removing character encoding error--> 

        <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.min.js"></script><!-- see the change here -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <span id="test">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').on('change',function(){
            var value=$(this).val();
            var output='';
            for(var i=1;i<=value;i++)
            {
                output+='<div>Your Text</div>';   
            }
            $('#test').html(output); //html will do everything(removing and then adding)
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

***Note:- You can once try like this:-***

`<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Just tried it and this was my solution! I just needed to download the jQuery library locally